# when the last image on the slider arrives...

Tags: jquery, html, css

the problem is when the last image move to the first (.gallery), makes the 'transition' to all images and it´s not enjoyable. the goal is to keep slide normally when start.
'http://jsfiddle.net/bfo8tase/1/'
html

```
    '<section>
     <div class="img-content">
        <div class="image-container">
            <ul class="gallery">
                <li><img src="http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/6801687-lovely-nature-wallpaper_DHT4Wju.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/6801687-lovely-nature-wallpaper_DHT4Wju.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/6801687-lovely-nature-wallpaper_DHT4Wju.jpg"></li>  
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div> 
        <div class="arrow-left">
            <div class="arrow-img"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow-right">
            <div class="arrow-img2"></div>
        </div>    
    </section>'
css

    '.arrow-left {
     position: absolute;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 80px;
     top: 42%;
     opacity: 0.7;
     width: 150px;
     height: 115px;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
     -webkit-transition: width 1s, background-color 1s;
      /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
     transition: width 1s, background-color 1s;
     left: 0;
   }
    .arrow-right {
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 80px;
    top: 42%;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: 150px;
    height: 115px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
   -webkit-transition: width 1s, background-color 1s;
   /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 1s, background-color 1s;
    }
    .arrow-left:hover, .arrow-right:hover {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .arrow-img {
    background-image: url(../img/navs.png);
    left: 0px;
    background-position: 2px 2px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 55px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 120px;
    }
   .arrow-img2 {
   position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    background-image: url(../img/navs.png);
    background-position: 99% -107px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 55px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 139px;
    }
    .image-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 546px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 49%;
    left: 38%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -48%);
    position: absolute;
    }
    .image-container img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    /*display: none;*/
    }
    .gallery {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .gallery li:nth-child(1){
    transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    .gallery li:nth-child(2){
    transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    .gallery li:nth-child(3){
    transform: translateX(200%);
    }
    .gallery li:nth-child(4){
    transform: translateX(300%);
    }
    .image-container li
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    }
    .image-container li.active {
    display: block;
    }'

js

    '$(document).ready(function() {
     var intervalo;
        function createInterval() {
        intervalo = setInterval(function() {        
    currentImage++;
    if(currentImage > totalImages){
      currentImage = 0;
    }
    arrow();
    },3000);
    }

    var currentImage = 0;
    var totalImages = $('.gallery li').length - 1;

    $('.arrow-right').on('mouseup touchend', function(){
    next();
    clearInterval(intervalo);
    createInterval();
    });

    $('.arrow-left').on('mouseup touchend', function(){
    previous();
    clearInterval(intervalo);
    createInterval();
    });

    function arrow() { $('.gallery').css({
    'transform' : 'translateX(-' + currentImage * 100 + '%)',
    '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(-' + currentImage * 100 + '%)',
    });
    }

   function next() {
    currentImage++;
    if(currentImage > totalImages)
      currentImage = 0
    arrow();
   }

   function previous() {
    currentImage--;
    if(currentImage < 0)
      currentImage = totalImages
    arrow();
   }
    createInterval();
    })'
```

.................. . . . . . ............................... . . .  ............................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're sliding the images, I don't believe there's a *simple* way to slide from the last image to the first image without modifying the DOM.

I've fiddled with the code enough to get the advancement from the last to the first image working smoothly (that is, sliding to the left and resetting, instead of sliding back to the right): http://jsfiddle.net/56tybtmh/

I was able to get it sliding correctly by duplicating the first image and adding it to the end. I'd recommend doing this programmatically so your HTML doesn't end up with duplicates, if you have the time:

```
<ul class="gallery">
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/6801687-lovely-nature-wallpaper_DHT4Wju.jpg">
    <div class="artistic-sub">100 x 80 cm, Acrylic on canvas</div>
  </li>
  <!-- Three other list items removed for brevity. -->
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/6801687-lovely-nature-wallpaper_DHT4Wju.jpg">
    <div class="artistic-sub">100 x 80 cm, Acrylic on canvas</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Once the extra element was in place, I modified the `next()` function behavior to scroll to the final image (which is a duplicate of the first) when it gets to the end of the line, then once it's finished, I disable the CSS transition with a CSS class (`.reset`):

```
.gallery.reset {
  transition: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
}
```

Once the animation is disabled, I reset the `translateX` property so the gallery element immediately scrolls to the first image (that way, the user doesn't see the non-enjoyable transition), and lastly remove the `.reset` class so the gallery can animate smoothly on the next call to `next()`:

```
function next() {
  currentImage++;
  if(currentImage >= totalImages) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      currentImage = 0
      $('.gallery')
        .addClass('reset')
        .css({
          'transform' : 'translateX(-' + currentImage * 100 + '%)',
          '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(-' + currentImage * 100 + '%)',
        })
      setTimeout(function() { $('.gallery').removeClass('reset'); }, 500);
    }, 500);
  }
  arrow();
}
```

There are two things my JSFiddle doesn't take into account:

- Similar changes need to be added to the `previous()` function in order to smoothly handle going from the first image to the last image.
- Much like your `clearInterval(intervalo);` call, you'll need to call `clearTimeout()` whenever a user taps the next or previous arrows to avoid resetting to the first image if the user taps the next or previous arrows too quickly.